# How do I install java on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: java

Is it possible to install java on my Raspberry Pi? If it is what are the commands I need to execute to install java?

Comment: google "java raspberry pi", second result: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html

also, this seems to work: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk`

Comment: @LuWi what is "Java® SE Embedded"? Is this a specific version of Java for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: it's a footprint-reduced version of java SE (Standard Edition), especially made for embedded systems with less-than-normal memory. But I think that gets installed with @recantha s code anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In newer distributions, Java is already installed so you might find you already have it.
If all else fails, try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
```